# How to insert a PHP string into a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

**BACKGROUND**

I have this table:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_valid`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_valid` (
  `user_valid_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_valid_idUP` int NOT NULL,
  `user_valid_firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_valid_lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_valid_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_valid_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_valid_email` (`user_valid_email`),
  KEY `user_valid_idUP` (`user_valid_idUP`),
  KEY `user_valid_firstname` (`user_valid_firstname`),
  KEY `user_valid_lastname` (`user_valid_lastname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
COMMIT;
```

And a PHP string

```
$non_formatted_csv = "12456,toto2,toto3,dummy@d.de,4556,tata2,tata3,dummy2@d.de";
```

that I would like to insert in the `users_valid` table.

**WHAT I DID SO FAR**

I thought I first have to split the string into chunks (so that I retrieve only 4 elements).

```
<?php //php 7.2.24
    $non_formatted_csv = "12456,toto2,toto3,dummy@d.de,4556,tata2,tata3,dummy2@d.de";
    $splitted_csv = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return implode(',', $value);
    },
   array_chunk(
        explode(',',  $non_formatted_csv),
        4
    )
);

  $lastElement = end($splitted_csv); 
  foreach( $splitted_csv as $k => $v) {
     var_dump($v);
      // This is where I sphould INSERT the 4 values in the table
    }

?>
```

But I am kind of stuck to INSERT the 4 values into the table.

Maybe a different (and more elegant) solution would be to create a JSON object and use the MySQL JSON_TABLE function. I kind of tried with no luck.
Best,
P

Comment: It is pretty unclear what your actual problem is or it should be the, very basic question of, how to insert data in a mysql table which is answered enough times on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I see nested function calls and then someone says "I'm stuck", the first thing I do is simplify things into multiple lines with (hopefully) better names. In doing this we can just get rid of the `$splitted_csv` variable which is confusing.

```php
// Original data
$non_formatted_csv = "12456,toto2,toto3,dummy@d.de,4556,tata2,tata3,dummy2@d.de";

// Break the text into an array and group 4 at a time
$csv_rows = array_chunk(
    explode(',', $non_formatted_csv),
    4
);
```

At this point, `$csv_rows` (with the test data) is now 2 rows, and each row has 4 values. Here's what it looks like:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12456
            [1] => toto2
            [2] => toto3
            [3] => dummy@d.de
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4556
            [1] => tata2
            [2] => tata3
            [3] => dummy2@d.de
        )

)
```

Now we just need to loop over that array. The comments in the code should hopefully explain the rest. I'm using a prepared statement which you should always use, and I happen to be using PDO but you can use whatever you need to. Obviously changed the database to what you need. Also, I have no idea what `user_valid_idUP` is in your database so I'm just blinding reusing the `user_valid_id` field. You can fix your logic as needed.

```php
// Database variables, change as needed
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'del_me';
$db_user = 'del_me';
$db_pass = 'del_me';

// Connect to database using PDO or whatever you want
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);

// Turn on loud errors, always!
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// This is the general insert code. I have no idea what user_valid_idUP is so I'm just setting it to the ID.
$statement = $link->prepare('
    INSERT INTO users_valid
        (user_valid_id, user_valid_idUP, user_valid_firstname, user_valid_lastname, user_valid_email)
    VALUES
       (:id, :id_up, :first_name, :last_name, :email)
       ');

// Loop over the rows
foreach ($csv_rows as $row) {

    // Sanity check that our data is valid
    if(4 !== count($row)){
        throw new RuntimeException('Wrong row count');
    }

    // Insert using array indexes and hope that the data is correct
    $statement->execute([
                            'id' => $row[0],
                            'id_up' => $row[0],
                            'first_name' => $row[1],
                            'last_name' => $row[2],
                            'email' => $row[3],
                        ]);
}
```

You'll notice I'm throwing an exception in the `for` loop for sanity-check reasons. If you **don't** do that, you'll instead get strange errors about indexes that in your error logs or on the page.

You'll hopefully also notice that I turned [PDO's error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) on for loud-mode. Doing this means that you don't have to check the results of statements as much because real exceptions will be thrown. For instance, if you run this code twice, the second time it should fail because of primary key violations, I'll leave that up to you.